# Integrating Twilio with Salesforce

Tags: salesforce, twilio, salesforce-lightning

I am trying to integrate Twilio with my Salesforce account, but I'm not sure how to go about it.
I followed the instructions on this page: https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Lightning_Open_CTI

I've uncommented the Twilio related code inside SoftphoneProviderHelper.
Also, inside Custom Settings, I've input my Twilio Account Sid and token.
But, I'm still unable to make/receive calls. What am I missing?

Comment: Were you able to get the demo adapter working without any changes? Are you seeing an error at all? Can you share as much information as possible about this.

Comment: Yes, I was able to get the demo adapter working. The only error I got was with the demo adapter. When I try to hang up a simulated call (after answering it), I get the following error: 
This page has an error. You might just need to refresh it. Action failed: c:connectedPanel$controller$endCall [Cannot read property 'length' of undefined] Failing descriptor: {c:connectedPanel$controller$endCall}

Comment: @philnash Another thing to mention is that I don't get any sound from the demo adapter. No dialtone, no ringtone, no dialpad tone etc.

I strongly feel that there are some steps that I'm missing. For example, I am yet to enter the 'fromNumber' anywhere, because I'm not sure where I should input it. 

I've tried hard coding my account sid, token and fromNumber inside SoftphoneProviderHelper Apex class, but no luck.

Comment: This sounds like problems with the adapter itself. The [GitHub project for it](https://github.com/developerforce/open-cti-demo-adapter) suggests getting in touch with the author, dlouvton@salesforce.com. Maybe give that a go?

Comment: Thanks, I'll write him an email.